# node creating instances via costructors

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, constructor, instance

While experimenting with nodejs I encountered a problem of enabling isntances creation via   Constructors.   I create simple cart basket functionality.
I got file cart.js

```
 var items = [];

function addItem (name, price) {
    items.push({
        name: name,
        price: price
    });
}

exports.total = function  () {
    return items.reduce(function (a,b) {         
        return a + b.price;
    }, 0);
};

exports.addItem = addItem;
```

I run it with  node

```
var cart = require('./cart')
```

But what if I need to create multiple instances of a Cart?

I tried to refactor my code, creating a Constructor, that holds `items[] addItem() and total()` functions,  like this:

```
    exports.Cart = function  () {

    var items = [];

    function addItem (name, price) {
    items.push({
        name: name,
        price: price
    });
    }

    function total () {
    return items.reduce(function (a,b) {        
        return a + b.price;
                                        }, 0);
    }
};
```

I run it like this:

```
var cart = require('./cart');
cart.addItem('Pepsi',199);       // no problem with this
cart2 = new cart.Cart();      // it gives me undefined can't be a function
```

I understand, that I can use PROTOTYPE property to add functions and props to my Cart
So I create a second file  cart2.js and place something like:

```
    function Cart () {
    this.items = [];
}


Cart.prototype.addItem = function (name, price) {
    this.items.push({
        name: name,
        price: price
    });
};

Cart.prototype.total =  function () {
    return this.items.reduce(function (a,b) {            
        return a + b.price;
                                        }, 0);
    };

module.exports = Cart;
```

And now it works. 
But in order to explore all possiblities, I want to know how I can solve it the first way I tried. When I can use it as  "instanceble" Class thing and as singleton thing, with only one instance, at the same time.

Can you please advice me how to solve it the way I wanted in the first place?
I'll appreciate if you provide some other ways to solve this task of creating instanceable Classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option might look like this:

```
exports.Cart = function  () {

    var items = [];
    // ...other private stuff...

    return {
        addItem: function (name, price) {
            items.push({
                name: name,
                price: price
            });
        },

        total: function() {
            return items.reduce(function (a,b) {
                return a + b.price;
            }, 0);
        }
       // ...other public stuff...
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
 var carts = require('carts');

 firstCart = carts.Cart();
 second = carts.Cart();
```

Comment: Thanks, Georg!    I didn't know about this way.  Now I'm equiped with this.  Thank you!